# Could not retrieve data in a sql query. Works in sql server but fails in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have following tables (CustomerType, Customer and Company) in a data base:

[image]

In asp.net, I am trying to write a query Like this to get some data which meets the criteria. My SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT co.[CompanyID], [CompanyName], co.[Address], co.[Phone], co.[Email], 
co.[WebPage] 
FROM [Company] AS co INNER JOIN [Customer] AS cu ON 
co.[CompanyID] = cu.[CompanyID]      
INNER JOIN [CustomerType] AS cut ON cu.[CustTypeID] = cut.[CustTypeID]
WHERE co.[CompanyID] = @CompanyID
AND cu.[CustTypeID] = @CustTypeID
AND cu.[CustTypeID] <> 11
```

I retrive the "CompnayID" AND "CustTypeID" From Query String. But when I test this Query in visual studio, it caused an error saying **"Failed to enable constraint. One or More rows contains values violating non null, unique, or FK constraint"**

How ever when I run the same query in SQL server management studio it retrieve data correctly. Why is that?

This is the query I wrote in SQL server management studio:

```
SELECT co.[CompanyID], [CompanyName], co.[Address], co.[Phone], co.[Email], 
co.[WebPage] 
FROM [Company] AS co INNER JOIN [Customer] AS cu 
ON co. [CompanyID] = cu.[CompanyID] 
INNER JOIN [CustomerType] AS cut ON cu.[CustTypeID] = cut.[CustTypeID]
WHERE co.[CompanyID] = 10001
AND cu.[CustTypeID] = 12
AND cu.[CustTypeID] <> 11
```

**Update:**:

I even Tried Simple query AS:

```
SELECT co.[CompanyID], [CompanyName] 
FROM [Company] AS co INNER JOIN [Customer] AS cu 
ON co. [CompanyID] = cu.[CompanyID]
```

This one also Causes the same problem, but works in sql server.

**Update 1:**
By adding "AND cu.CustID = @CustID", the sql query works fine. But I still don't understand Why my previous query doesn't work? can somebody explain?

This is my ASP.NET CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="CompanyID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="CompanyID" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CompanyID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
                    SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                    SortExpression="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WebPage" HeaderText="WebPage" 
                    SortExpression="WebPage" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ICT_IdealComputerConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT co.CompanyID, co.CompanyName, co.Address, co.Phone,
     co.Email, co.WebPage
     FROM  Customer AS cu INNER JOIN CustomerType AS cut ON cu.CustTypeID = 
     Cut.CustTypeID 
     INNER JOIN Company AS co ON cu.CompanyID = co.CompanyID 
     AND cu.CustTypeID = @CustTypeID AND co.CompanyID = @CompanyID AND cu.CustID = 
     @CustID AND cu.CustTypeID &lt;&gt; 11">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CustTypeID" QueryStringField="CustTypeID" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CompanyID" QueryStringField="CompanyID" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CustID" QueryStringField="CustID" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Try a simpler query first to make sure everything works: select top 10 * from Company

Comment: Yes this "select top 10 * from Company" works, and I tried like "SELECT co.[CompanyID], [CompanyName] FROM [Company] AS co INNER JOIN [Customer] AS cu ON co. [CompanyID] = cu.[CompanyID]". Even this join fails in Visual studio but works in Sql Server

Comment: What are you using to do your .NET data access; Entity Framework, Typed Datasets, raw ADO.NET? Can you show the .NET code you're trying to run?

Comment: @JamieSee I am using sqldatasource for a gridview.

Comment: Did you generate the DataKeys property when you set the GridView up, or have you let it be set automatically? If it's either of those two, then, what's likely to have happened is that when you did your originial query without the additional join filter, you got repeated rows, which in turn violated the DataKey (effectively a primary key) of the GridView. When you added the additional clause, you removed the duplicate rows and satisfied the DataKey criteria. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey.aspx

Comment: @dash Yes that should be the cause of the problem. y don't u post this as an answer? so that I can mark it as answer..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey.aspx) property - it's likely that a unique key has been created either intentionally or automatically.

Adding duplicate rows may then have caused the error you saw.

*Where would the duplicates come from?*

In your original query, without the customer id specified, if you have any company that is linked to more than 1 customer, you'll get duplicate rows as there is potentially a 1-To-Many relationship between Customer and Company (which makes sense as you could have multiple customers from the same company!).

When you filtered by customer, you then only got a list of unique companies for that customer, likely removing any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Fails in Visual Studio" I assume you mean that your program throws an exception when launched from the Visual Studio debugger?  That error means that the dataset/datastructure you are trying to put the data into has some not null constraints.  I can't tell from your screen shot which one it is, but for example, let's assume Contact is "Not null".  Since it isn't included in either of your queries the framework will try to set it to Null which will cause the constraint to fail.  Check to make sure you are including any non null (especially the CompanyID since it is the primary key) in the select clause of all your queries.

Comment: by adding "AND cu.CustID = @CustID" the query works Fine. My problem fixed but I am confused. Still don't understand why my previous code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From what can be inferred from your error description, it sounds like you are not setting the parameters @CompanyID and @CustTypeID parameters from your .NET code.

Comment: I sent the parameters correctly even I manually tried typing the value correctly on the browser.

Comment: Showing us your .NET code would help us narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On your Gridview,  DataKeyNames should be "CustId", which is a unique value.